# How to pass condition into lambda?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a dictionary like this:

```
Dict={'A':0.0697,'B':0.1136,'C':0.2227,'D':0.2725,'E':0.4555}
```

I want my output like this:
Return A,B,C,D,E if the value in my dataframe is **LESS THAN** 0.0697,0.1136,0.2227,0.2725,0.4555 respectively; else return F

I tried:

```
TrainTest['saga1'] = TrainTest['saga'].apply(lambda x,v: Dict[x] if x<=v else 'F')
```

But it returns an error:

```
TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: What does `TrainTest` look like?  Is it a DataFrame?  Can you show at least a small example of it?

Comment: Chances are using a 2-argument lambda on a pandas series isn't going to work, assuming that's what `TrainTest['saga']` is

Comment: Unrelated, but you say less than, but your code also checks equal to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's make some test data:

```
saga = pd.Series([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.9])
```

Next, recognize that `Dict` is a `dict` and has no ordering, so let's get that sorted by the numbers in reverse order:

```
thresh = sorted(Dict.items(), key=lambda t: t[1], reverse=True)
```

Finally, solve the problem by looping not over `saga` but over `thresh`, because loops (and `apply()`) in Python/Pandas are slow and we assume `saga` is much longer than `thresh`:

```
result = pd.Series('F', saga.index) # all F's to start
for name, value in thresh:
    result[saga < value] = name
```

Now `result` is a series of values A,B,C,D,E,F as appropriate--we loop in reverse order because e.g. 0 is smaller than all the values and should be labeled A, not E.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding run-times:

```
In [160]:%%timeit
# loop over smaller thresh, not << saga
for name, value in thresh:
    result[saga < value] = name
100 loops, best of 3: 2.59 ms per loop
```

Here are pandas run-times:

```
 saga1 = pd.DataFrame([0.05,0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.9],columns=['c1'])
 def mapF(s):
     # descending 
     curr='F'
     for name, value in thresh:
         if s < value:
             curr = name
     return curr
```

Using map/apply:

```
In [149]: %%timeit
saga1['result'] = saga1['c1'].map(lambda x: mapF(x) )
1000 loops, best of 3: 311 µs per loop
```

Using vectorization:

```
In [166]:%%timeit
import numpy as np
saga1['result'] = np.vectorize(mapF)(saga1['c1'])
1000 loops, best of 3: 244 µs per loop

** saga1 
+---+------+--------+
|   |  c1  | result |
+---+------+--------+
| 0 | 0.05 |   A    |
| 1 | 0.1  |   B    |
| 2 | 0.2  |   C    |
| 3 | 0.3  |   E    |
| 4 | 0.4  |   E    |
| 5 | 0.5  |   F    |
| 6 | 0.9  |   F    |
+---+------+--------+
```